# Overwrite Params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One of my functions creates new agencies. The params come from a form that is submitted and in my controller I use:

```
agency_params
      params.require(:agency).permit(:name, :cnpj, :country, :state, :city, :phone, :email, :platform_id)
end
```

In some cases (depending on the user role) I don't want to allow any platform_id but just a specific one.

So my idea was:

```
def agency_params
      params.require(:agency).permit(:name, :cnpj, :country, :state, :city, :phone, :email, :platform_id)

      if current_user.platform
        params[:platform_id] = current_user.platform.id
      end
    end
```

But this does not seem to work. How could I do that? Is the controller the right place, or better in the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think it should be `params[:agency][:platform_id] = current_user.platform.id`?

Comment: Thank worked. Thanks, @31piy

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are doing something like this in your controller method:

```
def new
    @agency = Agency.new(agency_params)
    ...
end
```

In that case, `agency_params` is returning a hash of parameters to pass to the `new` method. In your example, if `current_user.platform` is true, then `agency_params` does not return the parameter hash, but rather the result of `params[:platform_id] = current_user.platform_id`.

You need to modify `:platform_id` before returning the parameter hash:

```
def agency_params
    if current_user.platform
        params[:agency][:platform_id] = current_user.platform.id
    end
    params.require(:agency).permit(:name, :cnpj, :country, :state, :city, :phone, :email, :platform_id)
end
```